# can we create compact table(excel-like) from normal table using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

need to know that how can i form excel-like layout table from normal table.

Child node should come under parent node in next row with indentation.

[image: Excel-Like]

Comment: It's all just html and css

Comment: In what sense is that "compact", that a "normal" table isn't?

Comment: try Data Tables https://datatables.net/examples/

Comment: After forming standard table , i need to form excel-like table from that.